# @OneToMany mapping with Composite Primary Key not working as expected

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, composite-primary-key

I'm trying to implement a `OneToMany` mapping with a composite primary key in my application. The entities involved in the application are as follows:

```
// Config data
@Data
@Entity
public class Config {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "config", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private Set<Mapping> mappings;
}
```

The class with Composite key is:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Mapping {
    @EmbeddedId
    private MappingId mappingId;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<Integer> values;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Config config;
}
```

The composite key:

```
@Data
@Embeddable
public class MappingId implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String comment;
}
```

Now, I'm trying to save the following `Config` json data:

```
{
    "mappings": [
        {
            "mappingId": {
                "comment": "comment#1"
            },
            "values": [
                123,
                456
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The code is supposed to generate a value for `id` column automatically and assign it to both `Config.id` and `Mapping.mappingId.id`. But the values of these variables is not matching. After calling `save` method on `config` object, value of `Config.id` is set to `1` whereas `Mapping.mappingId.id` is set to `0` which is not correct. Can someone tell me what is going wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `@MapsId` annotation on your `Config config` attribute.

The `@MapsId` annotation tells Hibernate that the primary key of the associated entity shall be used as the primary key or as a part of a composite primary key. If you use it with a composite primary key, you need to reference the attribute to which the primary key value of the associated entity shall be mapped.

This mapping should set the value of `Config.id` as `Mapping.mappingId.id`:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Mapping {
    @EmbeddedId
    private MappingId mappingId;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<Integer> values;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @MapsId("id")
    private Config config;
}
```

And [here](https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tip-bidirectional-one-to-one-with-shared-composite-primary-key/) you can see a complete example of such a mapping.